# sed replace String with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to do the following using sed.

I have the following 2 strings:

```
#importantStr nonImportantStr
#importantStr nonImportantStr identifier
```

in some case I would like to remove the # from the fisrt string and in other case from the second.
for this question, lets assume I want to remove the # from the second while using 'identifier' in my regex.

I tried the following(and some other) with no success:

```
sed -r -i "s/\(^#importantStr\)\(.*\)\(identifier\) /importantStr/" /some/file/path
```

sed version is: GNU sed version 4.2.1

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I still don't understand the required logic. When should the `#` character be removed, and when shouldn't it? The "required logic" should make absolutely no reference to code or to your proposed *solution*; so, saying "while using **identifier** in my regex" does not qualify as a specification of your logic. What would qualify would be something like this: "I want to remove the leading `#` only on those lines that also include the word **identifier**". (And then you must be very precise: Only when the word is in all-lower-case? What if there is the plural word **identifiers**? Etc.)

Comment: let's assume that based on a parameter in the function where this code is written, I need to remove one of the #.
if param = 1, remove the # from the first string, if 0, remove from the second

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are somewhat unclear but here is a solution based on my understanding of the requirements.

```
$ cat infile
#importantStr nonImportantStr
#nonimportantStr nonImportantStr
#importantStr nonImportantStr identifier
#importantStr nonImportantStr identifier1
#otherStr nonImportantStr identifier
anotherStr nonImportantStr identifier

$ sed  's/\(^#\)\(importantStr\)\( .*identifier$\)/\2\3/' infile
#importantStr nonImportantStr
#nonimportantStr nonImportantStr
importantStr nonImportantStr identifier
#importantStr nonImportantStr identifier1
#otherStr nonImportantStr identifier
anotherStr nonImportantStr identifier
$
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
sed '/identifier$/s/^#//' file
#    < grep part><     >
#           substitution part
```